# Pymongo Updating Differently than Mongo Shell

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

While using Pymongo for updates, I do not get a result (or an error) that I get if I drop the same query into a shell, where `db=blog`

In the shell, this works:

```js
db.posts.update(
    {'permalink': 'TLxrBfyxTZjqOKqxgnUP'},
    {'$inc': {'comments.0.num_likes':1}});
```

While in Pymongo where `self.posts = blog.posts`, the following does not work

```js
self.posts.update({'permalink': 'TLxrBfyxTZjqOKqxgnUP'},
      {'$inc': {'comments.0.num_likes':1}})
```

I have also tried `comments.[0].num_likes` on a flyer...

There are no errors reported in the logs, and while this update returns 1 as the number of documents touched, which is correct, that data has not been altered.

Other non-indexed updates do work in both.

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

remember, `blog.posts` in a shell is string, but in python is a variable.

try:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
con = MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:"+port+"/blog")
db=con['blog']
db['posts'].update({'permalink': 'TLxrBfyxTZjqOKqxgnUP'},
                   {'$inc': {'comments.0.num_likes':1}})
```

Comment: While true, the db.posts was fed through correctly in the Python code as a parameter.